# CSS/HTML Responsive Fixed Sidebar Nav with Scrollable content window

Tags: html, css, dropdown, responsive

I'm quite basic in my coding and am working on a proof of concept design that has visible functionality. To do so, I'm looking to make a fixed, responsive, CSS dropdown menu to the left of the window and the main body being scrollable content.

Apologies for how remedial this may be. I have been playing around with the code on this section alone for almost two weeks now so I'm not sure that all my edits have been appropriately removed/etc.

My guess is that this has something to do with the CSS specificity I have used but I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is - at current, my displays aren't showing the profile image to the right side of the screen but instead, overlaps with the fixed sidebar.

"col-X" classes can be ignored unless someone can help with that as well. Tried to use a col spacing method but I was having further issues with the specificity of my CSS using the additional class so tried with the ID and Class elements I already specified to simplify.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Istok Web", "Barlow Semi Condensed", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*12 col style for responsive page

#col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

#col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

#col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

#col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

#col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

#col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

#col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

#col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

#col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

#col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

#col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

#col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

[id*="col-"] {
  float: left;
} */

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */

#sidenav {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 17%;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fc9497;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  color: #85e2ff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  color: #00BDF8;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #85e2ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  /*Remove col-3 width for total page width
  #col-3 {
    width: 100%;
  } */
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
}

#imagehead {
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagemask {
  display: block;
  max-width: 280px;
  right: 0;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.element {
  border: 2% #85e2ff;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/patientprofile.css">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Semi Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="sidenav">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show My Information</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href=#>My Health</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>My Appointments</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Results</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Scans</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>My Providers</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>Dr. Dolittle</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Ms. Shelly Sheldon</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Mr. Titus Anromidon</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="imagehead">
      <img class="imagemask" src="images/profile.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please just put code snippet which is not working instead of the entire code. becomes easier to resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks Pallavi - Will do in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps and hope that my assumption is right regarding what you are trying to achieve.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Istok Web", "Barlow Semi Condensed", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*12 col style for responsive page

#col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

#col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

#col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

#col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

#col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

#col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

#col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

#col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

#col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

#col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

#col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

#col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

[id*="col-"] {
  float: left;
} */

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */

#sidenav {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 17%;
}




/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fc9497;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  color: #85e2ff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  color: #00BDF8;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #85e2ff;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block !important;
}

#main {
  height: 150vh;  /** just to make it scrollable. can be removed */
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px calc(25% + 16px);
}

#imagehead {
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagemask {
  display: block;
  max-width: 280px;
  right: 0;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.element {
  border: 2% #85e2ff;
  border-radius: 2%;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    #sidenav {
      width:100%;
      left:0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 60px;
      padding-top: 16px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    #main {
       padding-left: 16px;
       padding-top: 60px;
    }

   /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul#menu {
    display:none;
  }

  /*Remove col-3 width for total page width
  #col-3 {
    width: 100%;
  } */


  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/patientprofile.css">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Semi Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="sidenav">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show My Information</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href=#>My Health</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>My Appointments</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Results</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Scans</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>My Providers</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>Dr. Dolittle</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Ms. Shelly Sheldon</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Mr. Titus Anromidon</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="imagehead">
      <h1>Profile</h1>
      <hr>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ea melius eligendi quaestio. Eam ludus 
         commune no, eu est percipit philosophia, ne has quando ullamcorper. Mel    
         euismod persequeris eu, eam in duis iusto concludaturque, postea efficiendi                           
         qui at. Nam te noster option efficiendi. Dicam apeirian scribentur ad pri. 
       </p>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ea melius eligendi quaestio. Eam ludus 
         commune no, eu est percipit philosophia, ne has quando ullamcorper. Mel    
         euismod persequeris eu, eam in duis iusto concludaturque, postea efficiendi                           
         qui at. Nam te noster option efficiendi. Dicam apeirian scribentur ad pri. 
       </p>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ea melius eligendi quaestio. Eam ludus 
         commune no, eu est percipit philosophia, ne has quando ullamcorper. Mel    
         euismod persequeris eu, eam in duis iusto concludaturque, postea efficiendi                           
         qui at. Nam te noster option efficiendi. Dicam apeirian scribentur ad pri. 
       </p>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ea melius eligendi quaestio. Eam ludus 
         commune no, eu est percipit philosophia, ne has quando ullamcorper. Mel    
         euismod persequeris eu, eam in duis iusto concludaturque, postea efficiendi                           
         qui at. Nam te noster option efficiendi. Dicam apeirian scribentur ad pri. 
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's great sawbeanraz. Got the mobile styles working as well! I tried to revisit that with the above codes but for some reason the changes still were not being taken.

Comment: Glad to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code below. Hope this works for you :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Istok Web", "Barlow Semi Condensed", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*12 col style for responsive page

#col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

#col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

#col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

#col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

#col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

#col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

#col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

#col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

#col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

#col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

#col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

#col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

[id*="col-"] {
  float: left;
} */

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */

#sidenav {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 10%;
  background: #fff;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fc9497;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  color: #85e2ff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  color: #00BDF8;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #85e2ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  /*Remove col-3 width for total page width
  #col-3 {
    width: 100%;
  } */
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}

#imagehead {
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagemask {
  display: block;
  max-width: 280px;
  right: 0;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.element {
  border: 2% #85e2ff;
  border-radius: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show My Information</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href=#>My Health</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>My Appointments</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Results</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href=#>My Scans</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>##/##/##</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=#>My Providers</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href=#>Dr. Dolittle</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Ms. Shelly Sheldon</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Mr. Titus Anromidon</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="imagehead">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
```